# Swashbuckle/Swagger with WebApi2 Identity Token

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to setup swagger using `Swashbuckle` for my Web API project. I am using `builtin` authentication (Asp.net Identity) and `builtin` default API path `/Token` for granting access token.

I've also managed to add this custom path to swagger spec. Is there a way to tell Swagger to use bearer token obtained from `/Token` to make authorized API calls to protected API areas?

I've tried enabling OAuth2 in `SwaggerConfig` with implicit and password options for flow parameter but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwashBuckle/Swagger - OAuth Resource Owner Password Flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929280/swashbuckle-swagger-oauth-resource-owner-password-flow)