# swagger oauth got it, so now what?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, swagger

I want to add the oauth2 authentication to my web API so i have created a spec with securitydefinitions:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "OauthSecurity": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "authorizationUrl": "http://localhost/oauth/dialog", 
        "flow": "implicit",
            "scopes": {
                "admin": "Admin scope",
                "user": "User scope",
                "media": "Media scope"
            }
    }
},
"security": [
    {
        "OauthSecurity": [
            "user"
        ]
    }
],
```

so it generated me some annotations on my API:

```
@io.swagger.annotations.Authorization(value = "OauthSecurity", scopes = {
        @io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope = "user", description = "User scope")
    })
```

So how do i continue now? I still can acces (curl without any headers or tokens or whatsover) my API without any trouble at all.

Sure i can create the auth endpdoint but i somehow miss the link between the generated API and oauth.

Comment: unless you specify what a user or media or admin scope specifies on the API side, i doubt this would work.

Comment: the whole api is now user scope with this setup. When i looked in the petstore example from swagger, they used read_pets and write_pets but did also not specify them explicitly http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Comment: Any update on this? I am also unable to find a good documentation on that topic.

Comment: @SuleymanArslan see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Been a while and according to [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/), by using OpenAPI 3.0 you can do:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oAuthSample:    # <---- arbitrary name
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2 with the implicit grant flow. [More info](https://api.example.com/docs/auth)
      flows:
        implicit:   # <---- OAuth flow(authorizationCode, implicit, password or clientCredentials)
          authorizationUrl: https://api.example.com/oauth2/authorize
          scopes:
            read_pets: read your pets
            write_pets: modify pets in your account
```

I currently am using [Bearer Auth](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/), which works pretty well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The thing is, we are currently using Swagger codegen to generate backend code and swagger codegen is not supporting OpenApi 3.0.

Comment: I am not using codegen but afaiu this should work: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.0-rc0