# Swagger UI - Oauth password flow, retrieve and add token to authorized requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, swagger, swagger-ui

I have just started using Swagger UI for ASP.Net API web project in MVC.
Most of the parts I understood properly except the authentication.

I am using OAuth ASP.Net Identity. following are my settings:

**SwaggerConfig.cs**

```
         c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                        .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                        .Flow("password")
                        .AuthorizationUrl("/api/Account/ExternalLogin")
                        .TokenUrl("/Token")
                        .Scopes(scopes =>
                        {
                            scopes.Add("values:read", "Read access to protected resources");
                            scopes.Add("values:write", "Write access to protected resources");
                        });

         c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();
```

**AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements.cs**

```
internal class AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            var authorizeAttributes = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>();

            if (!authorizeAttributes.Any())
                return;

            if (operation.security == null)
                operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

            var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                { "oauth2", Enumerable.Empty<string>() }
            };

            operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);

        }
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: "http://localhost:17527/swagger/docs/v1",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
</script>
```

Upon authorizing the /Token request from APP page.

[image: Successful authentication and I do get the access_token as well when I look in console]

But when I try to access values endpoint it throws an error.

[image]

and the reason for that is the request is missing the Bearer Token that should go in headers

I have already tried few solutions but was not able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried this recently,you have to put [Authorize] attribute in method level but not at controller level then it will works and sends Bearer token in each request.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check on both the ActionDescriptor and the ControllerDescriptor like this. It will prevent you from putting Authorize attributes on all your controller methods.

```
 public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
 {
        var authorizeAttributes = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() 
                                         ? apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                                         : apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>();

        if (!authorizeAttributes.Any())
            return;

        if (operation.security == null)
            operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

        var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { "oauth2", Enumerable.Empty<string>() }
        };

        operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
 }
```